# Which data type to use to store fractions?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqldatatypes

I have some values like 3/5, 90/100 etc.

I have to store these values in separate columns in my database.

I am confused as to which datatype to use for this purpose; which is faster for `insert` and `select` operations?

Comment: u mean like 3 out of 5 correct answers

Comment: if it is important to know the numerator and denominator then you are looking at perhaps a smallint pair. but if you need to quickly get you an seo_score for it why not compute it and save it as such, perhaps a decimal(5,2). that way your queries won't have the overhead of a computation on the fly

Comment: i am getting seo score as 92/100 from other script, i don't want to manipulate it, i just want to store it same way and display it same way. please suggest me the best way to do this.

Answer (score 5):

Two integers; Numerator and denominator. Insertion/storing will be pretty much the same speed for any data type which provides a reasonable representation of a fraction.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you need the information for.

If it is stored for calculation and storage, calculate the result (`0.92` instead of `92/100`) and store that as `decimal(1,5)`. But you can't easily calculate it backwards if you want to display it.

If it is stored to be displayed at a later time but never to be modified again (or at least not fast) you can store it as `varchar` but that will break sorting.

Or you could store the different elements (positives, negatives, totals, ... whatever) as `decimal(5,0)` and display / calculate it while using it.

And of course you can combine the above if you want to get the edge out of the computing time while selecting.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i have seo score 92/100 for a website, this was calculated from some php script i want to store it the same way and i don't make any changes and when user wants it, i have to display it same way like 92/100, so that, it is easy to understand.

Comment: Resist the temptation to use a String for number information.  You, or the future you or your successor will regret it.  Learned from many jobs.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant That depends. I would never use it alone, but if selection time is critical (and you're hunting nanos) it can be worth it. I don't think its appropriate in this scenario. But otoh I know very few about the OPs scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to keep the value the same, without storing it as a `DECIMAL`, so that it can be displayed back to the user in the same way:

**Use `VARCHAR`.**

Comment: without any further comments in what situations thats a good idea (and when not!) thats not a good idea.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer Since no maths needs to be performed on the SEO score, the OP just wants it to be displayed back to the user in the same format. Storing it in `VARCHAR` will preserve it in exactly the same format as it was `INSERT`ed in.